# How to retrieve activities using SOQL?

Tags: soql, tasks, activities, activityhistory

I like to retrieve activities of an account using SOQL like:

```
Past Activities
 - <Date> Email: <subject>, John A. sent an email to David K.
 - <Date> Email: <subject>, Brian G. sent an email to Sam B.
 - <Date> Meeting: <subject>, Jim T. had an event with Dave B.
```

I tried to query ActivityHistories, but how do I get the user / contact who sent / received an email and set up an event?

```
SELECT ( 
   SELECT ActivityType, Subject FROM ActivityHistories 
     WHERE IsDeleted = False ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC
 ) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<account id>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to querry OwnerId and PrimaryWhoID.

```
SELECT (
        SELECT ActivityType,PrimaryWhoId,OwnerId,Subject FROM ActivityHistories

) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<account id>'
```

**OwnerId** would be the one who sent the email /created that activity

**PrimaryWhoId** would be the contact/lead/account to whom the email was sent
0
You then have to querry User Table and (Lead / Account/Contact) table to find the name/email of the person the email was sent

Src : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm